# How to update Array object index when i delete a array object item from array in angualrjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my array object

```
var item = [
    {index:1, name: 'miraje'},
    {index:2, name: 'alamin'},
    {index:3, name: 'behestee'},
    {index:4, name: 'arif'},
    {index:5, name: 'riad'}
];
```

when i delete an object like index: 2 , and that time i want to update my index value like ..

```
   var item = [
            { index: 1, name: 'miraje'},
            { index: 2, name: 'behestee'},
            { index: 3, name: 'arif'},
            { index: 4, name: 'riad'}
         ];
```

Comment: Show code efforts

Comment: your accepted answer does not match the requirement with looking for `index = 2`. it uses a known index (`1`) of the array, which is not given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you remove element you can use `forEach()` loop to change indexes.

```js
var item = [
{index:1, name: 'miraje'},
{index:2, name: 'alamin'},
{index:3, name: 'behestee'},
{index:4, name: 'arif'},
{index:5, name: 'riad'}
];

item.splice(1, 1)
item.forEach((e, i) => e.index = i + 1)
console.log(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the object and alter the index property of each object,

**DEMO**

```js
i=1;
var item = [
{index:1, name: 'miraje'},
{index:2, name: 'alamin'},
{index:3, name: 'behestee'},
{index:4, name: 'arif'},
{index:5, name: 'riad'}
];
console.log(item);
delete item[ 2 ];
console.log(item);
item.forEach(function(obj) {
     obj.index = i;
     debugger;
     i++;
});
console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to find the item with `index`, delete it, and to update all following items.

```js
function deleteItem(array, index) {
    var i = 0, found = false;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (found) {
            --array[i].index;
            ++i;
            continue;
        }
        if (found = array[i].index === index) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            continue;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

var items = [{ index: 1, name: 'miraje' }, { index: 2, name: 'alamin' }, { index: 3, name: 'behestee' }, { index: 4, name: 'arif' }, { index: 5, name: 'riad' }];

deleteItem(items, 2);
console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for a variety, without modifying the original array an efficient O(n) approach would also be as follows. We can also provide a range to delete the elements as well...

The range is provided supplied with the array indices, not the object index properties.

```js
var item = [
    {index:1, name: 'miraje'},
    {index:2, name: 'alamin'},
    {index:3, name: 'behestee'},
    {index:4, name: 'arif'},
    {index:5, name: 'riad'}
];
function deleteObjectsFromArray(a,j,k){
  return a.reduceRight((p,c,i) => i >= j && i < k ? p
                                                  : i >= k ? (c.index -= k-j, p[c.index-1] = c, p)
                                                           : (p[c.index-1] = c, p),[]);
}

console.log(deleteObjectsFromArray(item,2,4));
```